# Making an array with text from terminal

Tags: java, arrays

I have some problems with making an array. What I'm supposed to to is to make an array that contains 5 text-strings with names from the terminal. How do I do this? I know how to make an array with my own values, but this was harder to solve than I expected. And yes, I'm new to programming ;)

Comment: Probably args is what you are getting from command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this program can help you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public abstract class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter number of elements");
        int num_of_elements = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
        String[] elements =new String[num_of_elements];
        for(int i = 0; i < num_of_elements; i++){
            System.out.println("Please enter an element");
            elements[i]= input.next() + " ";
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < num_of_elements; i++){
            System.out.println("[" + elements[i] + "]");
        }
    }
}
```

Test

```
Please enter number of elements
3
Please enter an element
H
Please enter an element
E
Please enter an element
Y
[H ]
[E ]
[Y ]
```

Test 2

```
Please enter number of elements
4
Please enter an element
Hello
Please enter an element
How
Please enter an element
are
Please enter an element
you?
[Hello ]
[How ]
[are ]
[you? ]
```

Answer (score 1):

A number of ways to do this:

```
String[] elements = new String[5];
for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
     System.out.println("Please enter an element");
     elements[i]= input.next();

}
```

that's exactly doing what you are looking for.